# inheritance just to share enum - dangerous?

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, multiple-inheritance

Whenever I want to share an enum among many files I will :-

- create a class e.g. `B` dedicated to the enum
- a class, which want to access to  the enum easily, will derived from `B`

Mostly, there will be one class for one enum. (1:1)

```
class B{
    public: enum EnumB{ E1,E2 };  
};
class C : public B{ /* .... access EnumB */}; //a kind of struct
class D : public B{ /* .... access EnumB */}; //a kind of widget/manager
```

This approach enables `C` and `D` to access `EnumB` **without any prefix** `B`.

I think it is OK, because I use those enum in a very-narrow scope. (2-4 classes)
[A SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2417665/using-inheritance-purely-to-share-common-functionality) also states it is OK to use inheritance for utility.

However, I don't find that it is a popular approach :-

- [a SO-qualified way to share enum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6133080/whats-the-proper-way-to-share-an-enum-across-multiple-files).
- [Share global enum inside a namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119095/sharing-enums-in-c-over-classes)

### Question

- How my approach is dangerous?       What is its disadvantages?

  In real case, I tend to multi-inherit many classes just for that.

  ```
  class ShadowEnum{ public: enum ShadowE{ SHADOW,NO_SHADOW};   };
  class ColorEnum{  public: enum ColorE{ RED,BLUE,GREEN,PURPLE } };  
  class LightType{  public: enum LightE{ L_SPHERE, L_CONE, L_SPOT};   };   
  class LightManager : public ShadowEnum, public ColorEnum,public LightType{
       /* some code */
  };
  ```
- Can it be a cause of a dread-diamond issue in future?

By the way, I think [enum-class](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#enum) is not in the scope of this question.

Comment: Whilst personally I wouldn't be inheriting from the enum specific class (I'd just accept the use of the prefix), but if you want to use inheritance it seems to me that private inheritance would meet your needs whilst also addressing some of concerns. Private inheritance doesn't imply the is-a relationship.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not "dangerous" per-se. It's just bad design.
Class inheritance is supposed to define an IS-A relationship.

When inheriting from something that isn't "natural", you tend to get problems later along the development road.

Some of this design implications that could affect you are:
1. Multiple inheritance of the same class in a deeper inheritance graph.
2. Pointer casts may be affected if you change the inheritance structure in the future (Which is something you don't want to happen just for a convenience inheritance)

A couple of better solutions:
1. Contain the enums in a namespace - use [#using namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace). Adding that in the header will propagate to any compilation unit that includes that header.
2. In C++11 you can just use [enum classes](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)  - Not in inheritance, but it gives you stronger type safety.

Comment: Thank..... In both solutions, I have to call `SomePrefix::` right?  .... `#using namespace` is not so cute - [I can't use it at class-level](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6326805/3577745).   .... "Pointer casts may be affected" possible?  It is just an enum (size~0), no  address shift...  please elaborate

Comment: @javaLover I agree with your considering "cannot limit `using` to class scope" impure. But pragmatically it is probably not a big issue: Often a file will only contain definitions for only one class anyway. In any case the code should be related, and it's not unlikely that much of it will need the enums. That need could even serve as a criteria for arranging code in files.

Comment: @javaLover I didn't get why you are putting enum in a `Some` class if you don't want to call as `Some::` ?

Comment: If it's only these classes than it may not be a problem. But if you have multiple such classes, and a deeper inheritance tree, it can lead to human mistakes in code maintenance. Having all these classes in an inheritance tree would imply that you need to document the intention and the rules, for the next programmer. If you don't very quickly some other programmer will add a convenient member to one of those classes (because he can). Then everything will get messed up.

Comment: @JustRufus  because I can't find a true better way.    The alternative are **1.** put it in namespace -> I still have to `Some::`  **2.** put it in a global scope -> too dangerous  **3.** put it in a class --> I have to call `Some::`, but I can also cheat by inheritance!

Comment: @javaLover and for the using namespace issue - It's not per class, but per compilation unit. So technically adding that "#using namespace" in the same header where you had the LightManager class declaration will indeed include that namespace into whatever classes that include that header.

Comment: Now that you say that: That there is an implicit conversion to the base classes containing enums may be a desired effect; i.e. one can pass a `LightManager` to a function expecting a Color, which doesn't seem unreasonable. This assumes that colors in the OP's code are generally communicated by the class `ColorEnum` and not directly by the enum `ColorE`. Whether that makes sense is debatable.

Comment: @Yochai Timmer  That makes sense!